# prove two rings are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a *commutative* ring with identity and $b ∈ R$. Let $T$ be the subring of all multiples of $b$. If $u$ is a unit in $R$ and $u∈T$, prove that $T=R$.

- I think the two rings are like $R=\{\text{identity}, b,u,\text{other elements}\}$, and $T=\{ab\mid a∈\mathbb{Z}\}$, do I make something wrong?
- $u$ is a unit in $R$ means that $ux=1$ has solution in $R$, but I saw some comments that $u=ab$, where $a, b∈R$, I know that $b∈R$, but how do we get $a∈R$?
- Some comments show that $u$ is also a unit in $T$ (how?)

Comment: Multiples of $b$ does not mean $a *b$ for $a \in \mathbb Z$. It refers to the set formed by multiplying $b$ by every element of the ring $R$ (and not just $\mathbb Z$). So, $T = \{br : r \in R\}$

Comment: Is the key of the question to show that b is a unit in R? then for any r∈R, r=(r*b-)*b which is the multiples of b, so that r=T? is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct. Alternately, there are answers,  so you can view and upvote/accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is a bit misleading; however, $\{mb:m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is generally not a subring of $R$, so it's very likely that the text means
$$
T=\{ab:a\in R\}
$$
which is an ideal of $R$, rather than just a subring.

Saying that $T$ contains a unit $u$ means:

1. $u=ab$ for some $a\in R$;
2. there exists $v\in R$ with $vu=1$.

As a consequence, $1=vu=v(ab)=(va)b$ implies $b$ is a unit. Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I got really confused about the sentence' multiples of b' before.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u \in T\subset R$ be aunit, and $T$ as you defined, then we want to prove that $T=R$ now to show this we do the clssical, we prove $R \subset T$, since then we are done, since we already have by definition the other inclusion.
Now Let $r \in R$ , this means that $$r=r\cdot 1.$$ As you already observed: $1= x \cdot u$ (the other direction is here more convenient and would not even make a problem in noncommutative rings, as left inverses are right inverses, but here we are in particular save thanks to commutativity) for some $x$, so lets throw that in:
$$r=r \cdot 1= r \cdot x\cdot u= $$
but since now $u \in T$ we have that $u$ is a scalar multiple of $b$, so there is a $y \in R$ such that $y\cdot b =u$. Throwing that in again yields now:
$$r=r \cdot 1= r \cdot x\cdot u=  r \cdot x\cdot y\cdot b =(r \cdot x\cdot y)\cdot b $$
but since $r \cdot x\cdot y\cdot b$ now defines an element in $R$ we get that the left end of the above equation is in $T$, but so has to be the right side (as they are linked by equalities). So we get $r \in T$ for all $r\in R$. In particular we get $R \subset T$, and hence $R=T$

Comment: thanks! I get it now